# Issue with na.rm = TRUE when combining multiple character columns using Unite from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, na.rm

When trying to combine multiple character columns using unite from dplyr, the `na.rm = TRUE` option does not remove NA.

Step by step:

1. Original dataset has 5 columns `word1:word5` [Image of the original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrrZ0.jpg)
2. Looking to combine `word1:word5` in a single column using code:

```r
    data_unite_5 <-  data_original_5 %>%
        unite("pentawords", word1:word5, sep=" ", na.rm=TRUE, remove=FALSE)
```

- Here's an image of the output: [data_unite_5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJIOy.jpg)

3. I've tried using `mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` but that did not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldnt figure out why na.rm did not work as intended with the unite function.

Comment: What did you expect? `unite` replaces the NAs by an empty string `""`. Hence, if there are only NAs the result is an empty string, i.e. `""`.

Comment: Never describe a problem as *"that did not work"*, describe it as e.g. *"I expected the rows where any of these five columns contain NAs to get dropped, but they didn't"*

Answer (score 0):

You have misinterpreted how the `na.rm` argument works for `unite`. Following the examples on the tidyverse page [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html), `z` is the `unite` of `x` and `y`.

With `na.rm = FALSE`

```r
#>   z     x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a_b   a     b    
#> 2 a_NA  a     NA   
#> 3 NA_b  NA    b    
#> 4 NA_NA NA    NA
```

With `na.rm = TRUE`

```r
#>   z     x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 "a_b" a     b    
#> 2 "a"   a     NA   
#> 3 "b"   NA    b    
#> 4 ""    NA    NA
```

Hence `na.rm` determines how `NA` values appear in the assembled strings (`pentrawords`) it does not drop rows from the data.

If you were wanting to remove the fourth row of the dataset, I would recommend `filter`.

```r
data_unite_5 <- data_original_5 %>%
  unite("pentawords", word1:word5, sep =" " , na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>%
  filter(pentawords != "")
```

Which will exclude from your output all empty strings.